# Se puede simplicar SELECT COUNT?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un sistema en donde tengo que contar cuantas persona femeninas y masculinas tengo registrado en un basa de datos he podido lograrlo pero veo que tiene muchas lineas de código mi pregunta es si esto se puede simplificar o así queda y no se puede hacer mas, por que la verdad funciona muy bien pero no quiero tener problemas de seguridad.

```
<?php  
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(genero_vecino) as contar FROM comunidad_vecino WHERE genero_vecino='Femenino'")
    or die('Error '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $woman = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(genero_vecino) as contar FROM comunidad_vecino WHERE genero_vecino='Masculino'")
    or die('Error '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $man = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    
                 ?>
                <p>VECINOS</p>
                Mujeres:</b> <?php echo $woman['contar'];?>
                Hombres:</b> <?php echo $man['contar']; ?>
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(genero_vecino) as contar FROM comunidad_vecino GROUP BY genero_vecino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu consulta es **segura** porque en ella no interviene ningún dato externo, por tanto, los datos que maneja no pueden ser manipulados para perpetrar un ataque de *inyección SQL*. Si interviniesen datos externos deberías usar **consultas preparadas**. No obstante, debes evitar mostrar mensajes internos haciendo uso de `mysqli_error`. Los hackers buscan siempre en ese tipo de mensajes porque podrían revelar para ellos información útil para atacar al sistema. Es mejor usar **mensajes de error personalizados**.

En cuanto a **simplificación**, puedes obtener ambos conteos en una sola consulta:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN `genero_vecino` = 'Femenino'  THEN 1 END) AS f,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN `genero_vecino` = 'Masculino' THEN 1 END) AS m
FROM `comunidad_vecino`;
```

Aquí los `CASE` irán sumando `1` a la columna `f` o a la columna `m` según sea `Femenino` o `Masculino`.

El código podría re-escribirse así:

```
<?php
    $sql="SELECT
            COUNT(CASE WHEN `genero_vecino` = 'Femenino'  THEN 1 END) AS f,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN `genero_vecino` = 'Masculino' THEN 1 END) AS m
           FROM `comunidad_vecino`";
    if ( $stmt=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) ){
        $mData=mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt);
        $html="<p>VECINOS</p>
                <p><b>Mujeres:</b> $mData[f]<br />
                <b>Hombres:</b> $mData[m]</p>";
    } else {
        # Evitar mostrar mensajes de mysqli_error
        $html="HUBO UN ERROR ... mensaje personalizado aquí";
    }
    echo $html;
```

He optado por un estilo de programación un poco más claro, evitando mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML, que produce un código mucho más difícil de analizar y de mantener.